# Trouble importing JsonFormat in IntelliJ

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, import

I am attempting to set up a library, but I am getting a Cannot resolve symbol 'JsonFormat' and 'JsonProperty' error. This is what I have.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
```

The maven pom file has the dependencies for com.fasterxml.jackson.core, so I am not sure why it is not recognizing these import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `jackson-annotations` dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Okay, I checked and it looks like I also had that dependency already in place. This is what I have.                                                                                            
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Works fine for me. Please share a link to the complete project and the IDE logs.

Comment: I deleted main.iml and that seemed to fix it. Although I don't really know why.

Comment: Downloading the last version fixed the problem (2021.2.3)